# Reflex: Delaying events based on a behavior

Tags: haskell, reflex

Using reflex-frp and reflex-dom I need to delay events based on a behavior.
I have:

```
delayEvent :: (MonadWidget t m, Reflex t) 
           => Event t () -> Behavior t NominalDiffTime -> m (Event t ())
delayEvent e b = switch . current <$> widgetHold (return never) eDelsM
  where
    eDelsM = (`delay` e) <$> b <@ e -- Event t (m (Event t ()))
```

however the return event never fires. Is there a simple mistake I'm making here or does the whole approach need rethinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the delay will never fire because when the widget defined by `eDelsM` is active from event `e0`, it will be waiting until the next event, `e1` to create a delay. However, by the time the next instance of the event fires, `e1`, a new instance of the `eDelsM` widget will become active and start waiting for the next instance of the event, `e2`.  The solution is to trigger a new event as soon as `eDelsM` is recreated.

```
eDelsM = (\t -> getPostBuild >>= delay t) <$> b <@ e
```